# Saving html code from multiple url

Tags: google-chrome

I have webpage “aaaa” providing a list of url “aaaa1”, aaaa2,...,aaaa100. I need to open each link and save the html code in a folder. Is there a way to open all the source code at the quickly (better than opening each link and fetch source, then copy it)?

More broadly, The problem is that I don't manage to open aaaa using python requests. I have the beautiful soup code to treat the html and extract the information I need from aaaa1, aaaa2, ..., aaaa100 source codes. I just don’t manage to open them in an other manner than doing it manually one by one. I need to move on and don’t mind doing it manually for now, but I just want to know whether there is a better way to do the manual part.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way than hitting each link and getting the source of page.
You can do something like this.

```
#assuming that your file has each link per line
with open('file_conataining_urls') as file:
   links = file.read().split('\n')
   for link_no, link in enumerate(links):
       f = open(link_no+'.html', 'w')
       f.write(str(requests.get(link).content))
       f.close()
```